# generate PDFs with unique content for each user in loop and send each pdf to its corresponding user's email - php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, pdf, mpdf

I'm running Wordpress and have multiple users. Each user should receive weekly report with some unique information related only to that user. Information should be collected in a PDF (using mpdf for generating pdfs) and send to each user's email correspondingly.

I have report.php file(I will run cron job on this file to send report weekly) and here is my code:

```
include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf = new mPDF();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'users', 
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ), 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1
);
$list = get_posts($args);
if($list){
    foreach($list as $suppItem){
        $userID = $suppItem->ID;
        ob_start();
        getUserReport($userID); /* this is the function which genarates html content
        for each user because the content of course for each user is unique */

        $x = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($x);
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $pdfName = 'weekly-report-'.$userID.'-'.$today.'.pdf';
        $content = $mpdf->Output($pdfName, 'S');
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $email = get_field('user_e_mail_address', $userID);
        if($email) {
            $mailto = $email;
        }
        $from_name = 'Website';
        $from_mail = 'info@example.com';
        $replyto = 'info@example.com';
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time())); 
        $subject = 'Weekly report of '.get_the_title($userID);
        $message = 'Attached find this week report.';
        $filename = $pdfName;

        $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\""."\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"."\r\n";  
        $finalmessage .= $message."\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\""."\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= $content."\r\n";
        $finalmessage .= "--".$uid."--";

        if (mail($mailto, $subject, $finalmessage, $header)) {
            echo 'Sent!';
        } else {
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm running above code, it sends emails to each user with PDF attached but the content is same for all. PDF file name is what expected but the content is wrong(except first item in a loop). Actually, first user's email body and PDF is correct, but rest user's PDF is same first user's content with some blank pages.

I've tried to move `$content = $mpdf->Output($pdfName, 'S');` outside foreach loop but in that case it collects all user's content together and sends in same PDF. But each user should receive its corresponding PDF.

I'm wondering what I'm missing inside/outside the loop so that it will send corresponding PDF to corresponding user email.

Comment: write `var_dump($x);` after `ob_end_clean();` what would be the result?

Comment: it returns each user's content @EniGma

Comment: everything what I `echo` or `var_dump` in this page works perfectly. But when sending pdf to each user separately, it doesn't work correctly. @EniGma

Comment: you have to add `$mpdf->Output(); exit;` after `if (mail($mailto, $subject, $finalmessage, $header)){}else{}`, what i mean is at the end of loop!

Comment: I added but now it is not working correctly at all: pdf is empty and only first user receives email with that empty pdf. @EniGma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Finally it is working. I tried to move this line (`$mpdf = new mPDF()`) into foreach loop and it works! Below you can see how my code looks like inside loop:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
ob_start();
getUserReport($userID);
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

I hope this will help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `ob_get_contents()` retrieve just the first entry every time. Can you clear `ob_get_contents()`? Or you could try to return the html code as string from the `getUserReport(...)`-Method.

**EDIT**

```
...
$html = getUserReport(...);  // get the report
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);     // write the report to pdf
$html = "";                  // clear the local variable
...
```

Comment: I tried to return the html from the `getUserReport()` function and it returns each user's info correctly @Patrick Vogt

Comment: This is great. And if you had put the html in the `WriteHTML(html)` function it doesnt work?

Comment: it works. The issue is when sending emails and how I described in mu question, it sends email to each user's email but the PDF content is same @Patrick Vogt

Comment: Could you try it like in my edit on my answer post? Maybe you have to clear the local variable after the `WriteHTML(...)` function.

Comment: I tried, but same result.`ob_start();$html = getSupplierReport($suppID); $html = ob_get_contents();ob_end_clean();$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);$html = "";`. Without `ob_get_contents()` it doesn't work at all @Patrick Vogt

Comment: Hm... Thats not quite good. Spontaneously I have no idea now. I have to think about it.